# How do I fix screen flickering on Lenovo F554L notebook?

Tags: drivers, display, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, i915

I had a perfectly fine laptop with lubuntu ruined by installing Lutris on it. No it has somehow ruined the display drivers. It now has an incessant flickering of the monitor that makes it almost impossible to use the machine.

I have tried the `lshw -c video` command that tells me that the machine has a Haswell-ULT integrated graphics controller. I used the linux-hardware.org site and it said I need the `drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_drv.c`.

I tried finding it on the smaun package manager on lubuntu, but only found the `xserver i9xx display driver`, which I reinstalled, but that did not seem to fix it either.